# Generate Binary Outcome Random Outcome Given A Probability

Tags: python, math, probability

I am designing code in Python that needs to generate a random outcome given a probability.

Example:
There are two possible outcomes: attack or no attack. Given a probability of 25% of an attack occurring, how do I generate an outcome based on that probability?

Comment: Have you tried googling something like "Python random"? This is an easily googlable question

Comment: generate a random number between 0 and 1, compare that number to 0.25

Comment: @PaulH why comparison we can select a item from `[1, 0, 0, 0]` if `1` its probability will be `0.25`

Comment: @ExplooreX an equally valid approach

Comment: @PaulH but random number is not generated purely with given probability rather it is pseudo random number

Comment: @ExplooreX that's true in both of our proposals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let represent `1 for ATTACK` and `0 for NO-ATTACK` and we create a `att_or_not` list in which selecting `1` is `0.25` so we use `random.randint(0, 3)` to select a item from list. **Check out logic here**

```
import random
rand_num = random.randint(0, 3)
def prob(rand_num, list_):
    if list_[rand_num]:
        return 'Attack'
    
    return 'No-Attack'
# [1, 0, 0, 0] => here 1 represent ATTACK and 0 represent NO_ATTACK
att_or_not = [1, 0, 0, 0]

result = prob(rand_num ,att_or_not)

print(result)
```